# Redex and reduction strategies

Tags: lambda

I'm studying [Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/), and have some trouble getting my head around the concepts of the 5th chapter, *The Untyped Lambda Calculus*.

Specifically, *redex*, *reduction* and the various evaluation strategies are doing my head in. The following is what I understand put into my own words, in an attempt to explain things to myself and get more knowledgeable people to correct my mistakes / imprecisions. I am honestly unsure as to whether this is an acceptable format for stackexchange, and am open to suggestions to make this a better fit.

Note that others have tried to answer a very similar question, but have still left me confused:

- [Call by value in the lambda calculus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168678/call-by-value-in-the-lambda-calculus)
- [Untyped lambda calculus: Why is call-by-value strict?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199563/untyped-lambda-calculus-why-is-call-by-value-strict)

### Redex

If my understanding is correct, a *redex* is a reducible expression, that is, the application of a lambda term to a lambda abstraction.

Or, more concretely, a redex is always of the form `(λx.s)t`.

### Redex reduction

Reducing `(λx.s)t` is done by replacing all free occurrences of `x` in `s` by `t`.
For example:

```
(λx.x + 2) 1
→ 1 + 2
→ 3
```

The process of reducing a lambda expression to its normal form is driven by an evaluation strategy: an algorithm for picking which redex to reduce first. In order to describe these however, we need some more vocabulary.

### Redex qualifications

#### Leftmost and rightmost

- the *leftmost redex* is the one whose abstraction is textually to the left of all other redexes.
- the *rightmost redex* is the one whose abstraction is textually to the right of all other redexes.

So, for example, in `(λx.x + 2) (λy.y + 1)`, we have:

- leftmost redex: `λx.x + 2`
- rightmost redex: `λy.y + 1`

There can only be one leftmost and one rightmost redex in a given expression. I'm assuming that in an expression composed of a single redex, that redex is both the leftmost and the rightmost.

#### Innermost and outermost

- an *innermost redex* is one that contains no other redex.
- an *outermost redex* is one that is contained within no other redex.

So, for example, in `(λx.(λy.y + 1) x) 2`, we have:

- innermost: `λy.y + 1`, as it contains no other redex.
- outermost: `λx.[...]`, as it isn't contained in any other redex.

I'm assuming that in an expression composed of a single redex, that redex is both outermost and innermost.

### Evaluation strategies

Having defined this, we can talk about the two evaluation strategies that I'm struggling with: *call by name* and *call by value*.

#### Call by name

In *call by name*, the leftmost outermost redex is always picked for reduction. Additionally, no reduction can occur within a lambda abstraction.
The example given by *Types and Programming Languages* is:

```
id (id (λz. id z)) # the leftmost, outermost redex is the very first id
→ id (λz. id z)    # the leftmost, outermost redex is still the first id
→ λz. id z         # there is no outermost redex remaining, we're done.
```

I do not understand the need for the definition of the strategy to include *no reduction can occur within a lambda abstraction*: is that not implied by the fact that only outermost redexes are eligible for reduction?

#### Call by value

In *call by value* the rightmost outermost redex is always picked for reduction.
The example given by *Types and Programming Languages* is:

```
id (id (λz. id z)) # the rightmost, outermost redex is the second id
→ id (λz. id z)    # the rightmost, outermost redex is the first id
                   # (it's textualy on the left, but there is no redex to its right)
→ λz. id z         # the only remaining redex is not outermost (it's contained within
                   # an abstraction) and cannot be reduced.
```

Comment: Hi! It's hard to understand what your _question_ is from this post. You've given a lot of detail and description of some fundamental programming constructs, but it's not clear what your puzzle is nor how it would be applied. If you're having general difficulty with the concepts, you may be better off jumping on the chat channel and seeking help there.

Comment: I'm essentially asking "this is what I understand, as clearly as I can make it out, where am I wrong and why?". I agree that it's probably not as suited to a q&a site as I felt it would be when I asked the question...

Comment: How about pulling out a specific applied example, and seeing if you can make a bounded question out of that. Then move onto the next piece you have trouble with...

Answer (score 6):

In Call by name:

> I do not understand the need for the definition of the strategy to
>   include no reduction can occur within a lambda abstraction: is that
>   not implied by the fact that only outermost redexes are eligible for
>   reduction?

No.
According to your definition of outermost, a redex is outermost if it is not contained within any other redex. 
In the following code, `id z` is the outermost redex, not `λz. id z` (which is an abstraction, not a redex).

```
id (id (λz. id z)) # the leftmost, outermost redex is the very first id
→ id (λz. id z)    # the leftmost, outermost redex is still the first id
→ λz. id z         # there is no outermost redex remaining, we're done.
```

Note that in the description of call by value in TAPL, there is a missing word in the definition of value:

> p 57, definition of call-by-value
>
> "a term that is finished computing..." should be "a CLOSED term that is
>   finished computing..."

This is probably the reason for your confusion.

Edited to add:
It turns out that the author's description of call-by-value is inconsistent with the operational semantics given in the book for the untyped lambda-calculus under call-by-value evaluation. 
According to the description of call-by-value on page 57, `λx. id id` would evaluate to `λx. id` since `id` is a value. (a closed term that cannot be reduced) and `id id` is the outermost redex. However the operational semantics (on page 72) do not have a rule that can reduce this term in this way. In addition, on the same page the author writes "Since (call-by-value) evaluation stops when it reaches a lambda, values can be arbitrary lambda-terms" suggesting that reductions are not allowed inside abstractions.

In the description of call-by-name, the author mentions that no reductions are allowed inside abstractions but neglects to do so in the description of call-by-value.

Second edit:
I believe the correction that adds the word "CLOSED" to the definition of call-by-value that I mentioned above causes an inconsistency with the operational semantics. 
For instance, `id (λx. x y)` reduces to `λx. x y` according to the operational semantics given. (Since values are arbitrary lambda-abstractions and the rule 'E-AppAbs' applies here) However, `λx. x y` is not a closed term since the occurrence of `y` in it is not bound.

Errata for the book are available at:
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/errata.txt

Answer (score -1):

You said outermost redex of (λx.(λy.y + 1) x) 2 is λx.[...] but redex is of the form (λx.s)t. λx.[...] is not of this form but whole expression (λx.(λy.y + 1) x) 2 is. So whole expression is outermost redex.